# Convert timestemp in pandas dataframe to a special format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df_data_raw` that has a column with the name "timestemp". This column has timestemp information in the format "2022-05-01 00:15:00+00:00" for every 15 minutes. I would like to convert this time information into the following format "01.05.2022 00:15". Can you tell me how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Please note that [ask] specifically says *not* to use screenshots of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
```

```
s = '2022-05-01 00:15:00+00:00'
print(pd.to_datetime(s).strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'))

01.05.2022 00:15
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with the [`'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) format:

```
df_data_raw['timestemp'] = (pd.to_datetime(df_data_raw['timestemp'])
                              .dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
                            )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

```
import datetime

timestamp = "2022-05-01 00:15:00+00:00"
dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00:00")
dt_string = dt_obj.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
print(dt_string)
```

Output

```
01.05.2022 00:15:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pd.to_datetime with the appropriate format argument.

```
pd.to_datetime(df_data_raw['timestemp'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
```